# how do I set up passkit entitlements in Xcode

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, passbook

I have created a pass id in the provisioning profile, generated the certificate and private key, and our server code can generate passes. However I cannot figure out how to make the project entitlements work with passkit. How do you associate a pass id with your app id or bundle id or something? XCode shows the option "Use pass type identifiers from the provisioning profile". Yet it doesn't appear to be anything in the portal to connect a profile with a pass id.

I can run things in debug on my local device, but how without the entitlements I can't distribute this to anyone.

Clearly I am missing some magic and all the docs talk about is building passes and using them, but nothing about building entitlements. Any ideas?

Comment: how did you solve your problem - did you find a way to set things up in Xcode?

Comment: see the answer I added, nothing is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the answer is, nothing. The Xcode user interface is confusing but apparently you don't have to do anything to support any pass id that your organization created. Passes are unique to your developer account, not any specific of your apps.

For once I wish Apple would actually document new features in the XCode UI.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect it to just work. Apple is strange - They should have said `Your app only has access to passes created with your Developer Account's Pass Type IDs` instead of `Your app only has access to certain passes, based on its entitlements`